# Running flask app in conda virtual environment

Tags: python, flask, conda

I am very new to flask trying to run my flask app from conda virtual environment, the steps I've taken are as follow. In Anaconda Prompt (base), I run:

```
conda activate P:\muPythonEnv
```

then I navigate where the app.py is:

```
cd P:\Documents\Python Scripts\newPythonEnv\Reine\reactFlaskTutorial
```

After I do

```
set FLASK_APP = app
set FLASK_ENV = development
flask run
```

for which I get the following error:

```
 * Serving Flask app 'app' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]

Error: While importing 'app', an ImportError was raised.
```

I wonder what am I doing wrong here? is it not possible to run flask in conda vm? also despite I set the end to development I still get a Warning, why is that so?

Comment: Did you had time to look at my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70313262/4413446)? It would be nice to have your feedback.

Comment: @Romain thank you for the answer, I am checking it today and will get back - also apologies for the late reply. I will get back to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing has nothing to do with `conda`, as we can see in the logs, `flask` package is found.

The problem is related to a module you use in your code that is not available in the conda environment. You need to check imports in your code and check if the corresponding packages are available in your conda environment by running `conda list`.

The warning you have is to tell you that running the flask embedded web server is not a good option for production see [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/cli/#run-the-development-server) for more information and deployment options.

Comment: thank you, indeed the issue was with a couple of packages that were not installed properly. Sorry for delay...